# There has been an error processing your request error while going to the page

Tags: magento-1.9

I go to some page and after that I see

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 1480226950850

In report-> 1480226950850

> a:5:{i:0;s:51:"Controller file was loaded but class does not 
>   exist";i:1;s:1066:"#0 
>   /var/www/hosts/mage-composer/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(340):
>   Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Controller file...')  #1
>   /var/www/hosts/mage-composer/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(308):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_includeControllerClass('/var/www/hosts/...', 'Agents_Agent_Fi...')  #2
>   /var/www/hosts/mage-composer/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(196):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_validateControllerClassName('Agents_Agent',
>   'finalize')  #3
>   /var/www/hosts/mage-composer/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>    #4 /var/www/hosts/mage-composer/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()  #5
>   /var/www/hosts/mage-composer/src/app/Mage.php(692):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)  #6
>   /var/www/hosts/mage-composer/src/index.php(83): Mage::run('chny',
>   'store')  #7
>   {main}";s:3:"url";s:21:"/agent/finalize/rend/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:4:"chny";}

What should I do? How I can fix it?

Comment: check the controller class name

Comment: @Piyush and how it must named?

Comment: Its class name should be Namespace_Module_nameController

Comment: @Piyush class name of my controller?

Comment: @Piyush I was check it, it was ok

Comment: Hello Any solution?